# I have a weird CSS problem: the contents of my page are filling the page height 100%

Tags: css

First, I set the height of the outer most object `html` to `100%`. I then set the `min-height` of the body to `100%`. The page has 2 containers: `header` and `article`. The header is `90px` in height. The `article` is `calc(100% - 90px)`.

I added some contents to the article container as it was not displaying without it.

I read an article that talked about adding vendor prefixes for calc, so `-moz-calc`, `-webkit-calc`. That did not work. The `article` is only extending to wrap its contents. If you run the code you will notice that the `article` container is not extending to the bottom of the page.

I checked `caniuse.com` and found that most browsers support `calc()`. I do find that if I specify the `height` in `px`, it extends correctly, but since the site supports mobile I do not know the height of each device.

I did notice that changing `100%` to `100vh` the `article` now extends to the bottom of the page. I believe that with the `height 100%`, `article` is extending to the height of the parent object which in this case is the `body` tag. Since `body` is `100%`. I’m stumped. I tested this on an iPad and it worked properly. On a Galaxy S5 it did not extend 100%. Maybe the phone does not support vh since it’s a bit older. I did a remote debug with my phone and computer through Chrome and found that the chrome browser likes `–webkit-calc()`. The weird thing is that with the phone in portrait mode it’s calculation `100vh` as half the height of the screen.

Here is my code in as simple a form as I can make it:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #acacac;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

article {
  min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 90px) !important;
  min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 90px) !important;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 90px) !important;
  background-color: white;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<article>
  <br />
  <div style="background-color:green; width:50%; height:200px; margin:0 auto">bbb</div>
  <br />
</article>
```

Comment: There's no attribute `passing: 0;` in CSS specification as you defined it in `body` element

Comment: You switched your example code to use `100vh` and appears to be working properly. The white background of `article` is extending to the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: passing should have been padding. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` won't give you 100% of the height of the viewport, only of the page content (or parent element). `height:100vh` (viewport height) seems to be working for most browsers for you, right? So maybe it's figuring out why it's not working correctly on certain devices? This article may help. https://www.lullabot.com/articles/unexpected-power-of-viewport-units-in-css

(Need more info to figure out why it's not behaving as expected with viewport height on your phone.)

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear. When you mention `height: 100%`, are you referring to the `html`, `body`, or `article` element?

Comment: When I mention `height:100%`, I'm referring to any element where the OP has used `height:100%` -- in this current case, `html` and `body`.

(In the original code, `article` does not have a `height:100%` applied to it, so not that.)

Except in rare cases, I generally don't apply attributes to my html element (because it's the body that is the first visible element in the viewport), but some folks still do (browser support has historically been mixed for styling the html element). In this case, `100vh` of the `html` element and `100vh` of the `body` element are going to be the same value.

Comment: Well, 1) you should clarify your answer and 2) it's not accurate when talking about `html` and `body`. When `height: 100%;` is applied to `html` and `body`, `body` will be 100% of the viewport height. Percentage heights require their parent element to have a height. When the element is `html`, the viewport will be the reference for `height: 100%` and match it. Thus why people add `height: 100%;` to `html` and not `body` alone - `body` inherits from `html` which inherits from the viewport.

Comment: You're right that applying `height:100%` to `html` will fill the viewport vertically on modern browsers. However, after doing so, setting body to `height:100%` will not fill the entire viewport. https://jsfiddle.net/kerri9494/qeswv7pa/

Comment: `body` is the same height as the viewport. We can debate if it _"does not **fill** the viewport."_ It _sort of_ looks like it might not because of margins on `body` and the content of `body`.

Answer (score 0):

height 100% only works if there is a parent element with a position and a fixed height. 
If you don't have that, you need to use 100vh (viewport height). Keep in mind that 100vh does not represent the full screen on some touch devices (ipad) as some of the toolbars are not respected in the calculation.

Comment: You don't need a position, just a height on the parent for `height: 100%;` to work.

Comment: I just tried while remote debugging to set the height of article, the parent( body tag) and HTML all to 100%. i'm only getting the page to fill 602px rather than the whole page. I did try vh, but that too did not work. in order to get the page to load correctly on my android phone I need to set HTML to 145vh, but that will cause pages to be too long on PC.